# net-snmp: how should I approach the project of making a bilingual snmpd?

Tags: snmp, embedded-linux, net-snmp, snmpd

I apologize that this question comes from the uninformed, huddled masses: I've been away from net-snmp for three years and I've missed all of the developments.

I have to deliver a bilingual v2c/v3 snmpd for use in an embedded Linux system.

I expect to use the superb net-snmp sources. What is the right approach to marshalling these sources, where "right" == straightforward, uncomplicated, vanilla, and "it just works"?

Thanks so much, everybody. And I apologize again for my out-of-dateness.

**Edit:** Why do I need this input? I have a lot of experience with snmp v2c in general; some experience with net-snmp; and little experience with snmp v3. Because I'm new to v3, I'm looking for a cookbook approach from someone who's done it so I can avoid the many undocumented pitfalls and hurdles that my experience tells me lie in the path of anyone building an agent from net-snmp sources.

Comment: Could you tell us more about why you need input?  What are the specific challenges that you need to overcome?

Comment: @Mike Pennington -- Please see my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, Net-SNMP is already tri-lingual under the hood.  If you configure it to accept v1, v2c and v3 it'll happily accept and respond to all 3 protocol versions without changing a thing.

Second, to get snmpv1/2c working, all you need in your snmpd.conf file is:

```
rocommunity COMMUNITYNAME
```

Where, `COMMUNITYNAME` is the super-secret insecure community/password you want to use.

For SNMPv3, I'm assuming you want to use SNMPv3 with USM.  I suggest you start by reading the Net-SNMP tutorial on [Securing SNMP traffic](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Security) and go from there.

Note also, you can run `snmpconf -g basic_setup` to get more help with the above as well as with other options.